# Strange files in $Windows.~WS folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, temporary-files

Screenshot of what I am talking about - 
[image: The files]

I have some strange files in the $Windows.~WS folder that are TMP files. The files automatically start downloading whenever I start BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service). All three files are of the same size and the total size of this folder is around **9 GB**(and it took 9 GBs of my **LIMITED** internet to download them. They consume a lot of internet whenever they download, so can I delete these files? I am on a limited internet connection. However, I want to download Windows 10 and if these files are related to Windows 10 then I won't delete them. Please give me advice on what should I do, I really want to download Windows 10 and saving internet for that!

Comment: Leave them until your upgrade is complete. They are part of the upgrade process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING:** *If you are upgrading to Windows 10 and **THAT IS NOT COMPLETE**, then leave these files alone until that finishes as these are needed for that process to finish 100%. Once that process is fully complete, you can follow the below instructions to clean these up afterwards only.*

**AFTER CONFIRMING YOUR WINDOWS 10 UPGRADE IS COMPLETE (see below)**

If you recently upgraded to Windows 10 (and that is ***FULLY COMPLETE***), these are likely related to that.  Run `Disk Cleanup` to start with but run it as administrator (*right-click* `run as administator`), and select the `Previous Windows Installation` option.

**Look here for Disk Cleanup instructions on Windows 10:**

http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-post-install-clean

**Here's another article (below link) that shows a command line cleanup syntax to run.**

*You'd open your command prompt and run as administrator, and then run these commands (paste and then press Enter).*

```
takeown /F C:\$Windows.~BT\* /R /A 
icacls C:\$Windows.~BT\*.* /T /grant administrators:F 
rmdir /S /Q C:\$Windows.~BT\
```

*and*

```
takeown /F C:\$Windows.~WS\* /R /A 
icacls C:\$Windows.~WS\*.* /T /grant administrators:F 
rmdir /S /Q C:\$Windows.~WS\
```

**Source:** http://www.thewindowsclub.com/delete-windows-bt-ws-folders-windows-10

Comment: "However, I want to download Windows 10 and if these files are related to Windows 10 then I won't delete them" - he **hasn't upgraded yet** so it's not a good idea for him to delete them.

Comment: Perfect.......;)

Comment: This is not enough to be able to delete the C:\$Windows.~BT\NewOS\" subfolders. Do you happen to know extra tricks or tools that figure out how to delete these? They appeared on my Windows Insider install, during a botched build upgrade. For the moment I've just moved the folder so Windows Update is happy again.